# Is there any way to write every warning in a .txt file in python?

Tags: python, compiler-warnings

I would like my program to write every warning in a .txt file. Is there any way to do this without using catch_warnings?

Comment: Yes it is possible. Open/create a file and then write to it.

Comment: @Terry That seems pretty unrelated to Python warnings.

Comment: I added the "compiler-warnings" tag. Although Python obviously doesn't have a compiler, its built-in warnings are basically analgous to compiler warnings in other langauges, so it seemed most appropriate.

Comment: @Tomerikoo They are talking about [Python warnings](https://docs.python.org/3/library/warnings.html) which are different from exceptions.

Comment: @ArthurTacca oh I see. That was not very clear from the question (I am not familiar with that module...). Thanks. In that case it seems your answer solves this

Comment: @Tomerikoo Can you vote to reopen? The two linked questions are totally unrelated.

Comment: @ArthurTacca I did as those dups apparently are not relevant although I would leave the question closed as unclear... +1 to your answer anyway

Comment: But I have another answer to add that is substantially different, and I think would be useful to people searching for this in future. It's perfectly clear if you know what Python warnings are. I think almost all StackOverflow questions wouldn't make sense if you don't know anything about the domain.

Comment: @ArthurTacca *Perfectly* clear is a bit of an overstatement... Saying *I would like my program to write every warning* is very general. An opener saying *I am using the warnings module* with a link will be perfectly clear. Anyway, I don't think there is a reason for 2 answers. Just edit it in

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One option is to use the built-in Python logging. There is a lot of information on the internet about how to use the Python logging system, especially in the Python documentation for it (e.g. see the [Logging HOWTO](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging.html)). But the simplest way to turn on logging to a file is with the [`basicConfig()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#logging.basicConfig) function, like this:

```
import logging
logging.basicConfig(filename="myfile.txt",level=logging.DEBUG)
```

Now you can enable logging of warnings with the [`captureWarnings()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#logging.captureWarnings) function:

```
logging.captureWarnings(True)
```

As a bonus, you can now also log your own messages:

```
logging.info("My own message")
```

---

An alternative is to replace the warning handler yourself. This is slightly more work but it is a bit more focused on just warnings. The `warning` module documentation for [`showwarning()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/warnings.html#warnings.showwarning) says:

> You may replace this function with any callable by assigning to `warnings.showwarning`.

So you could define your own function with the same parameter list, and assign it to that variable:

```
warning_file = open("warnings.txt", "w")

def mywarning(message, category, filename, lineno, file=None, line=None):
    warning_file.write(warnings.formatwarning(message, category, filename, lineno, file, line))

warnings.showwarning = mywarning
```

Note that I've opened `warning_file` outside the function so it will be opened once when your Python script starts. I also used the [`formatwarning()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/warnings.html#warnings.formatwarning) function so that the output is the same format as the `warnings` module usually outputs.